# How to make the Button visible one by one when I remove last char

Tags: java, android, view, android-button, visible

> I have textview typing in it by using buttons and every button clicked it will be invisible

```
backspace.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //extra code remove last char
                    //txt.setText(txt.getText().toString().substring(0, txt.getText().toString().length() - 1));
                        StringBuffer easer = new StringBuffer(txt.getText());
                        easer.reverse();
                        easer.deleteCharAt(0);
                        easer.reverse();
                        String x = new String(easer);
                        txt.setText(x);
                        //my button 1 get char from array
                        b1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                       //my button 2 get char from array
                        b2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                       //my button 3 get char from array
                        b3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                       //my button 4 get char from array
                        b4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                       //my button 5 get char from array
                        b5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });//end click listener
```

Comment: Be more clear when you ask for a problem

Comment: Can you elaborate what your issue is.

Comment: I have 10 buttons and 1 textview

Comment: I have 10 buttons and 1 textview , every button get char from array, and I need typing in textview by using these buttons then evey button get invisible if it clicked my question how to visible button when I click backspace button

Answer (score 0):

If your buttons have text that appear in your TextView then you can use **TextWatcher**. With the help of **TextWatcher** you may get event **afterTextChanged(Editable arg0)**. In that function you can set condition related to your text and visible button after **backspace** button clicked.

If this is not what you wanted then please specify your question a bit more.